# How to fetch merge request analytics with the gitlab api?

Tags: api, merge, gitlab, analytics

I have been reading the [gitlab merge request api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html) docs and [Group activity analytics api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/group_activity_analytics.html)  to find a way to fetch the "Mean time to merge" for a bunch of projects in my group.
but i have not been succesful.

Comment: Looking for the same. Have you found anything in the end?

Comment: You could argue you can get to the same data by querying the system with the MR API and then combine the data together in code, but then you would be re-inventing the wheel (the analytics available in GitLab in this case) and defeat the purpose of using the analytics in the first place

Comment: Yes i used @gitbeaker/node, i certainly could have just used their api directly, but i didnt have time, but gitlab doesnt seem to have an endpoint to fetch the data their displaying in their MR analytics, so i had to calculate the averages my self, fetching MR created in a range and ofc doing the mean of the creation date and merge date.